# JavaScript get character in sting after [ and before ]

Tags: javascript, function

I have some strings like:

```
str1 = "Point[A,B]"
str2 = "Segment[A,B]"
str3 = "Circle[C,D]"
str4 = "Point[Q,L]"
```

Now I want to have function that gives me character after "[" and the character before "]". How could I make something like that ?

Comment: Are A and B in `[A,B]` always one character?

Comment: @Kay Oh that is an good point! Actually no!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this one...

```
var str = "Point[A,B]";
var start_pos = str.indexOf('[') + 1;
var end_pos = str.indexOf(']',start_pos);
var text_to_get = str.substring(start_pos,end_pos)
alert(text_to_get);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use match() to extract the characters:

```
str.match(/\[(.*)\]/)[1]
```

A safer way would be:

```
var matches = str.match(/\[(.*)\]/);
if(matches) {
   var chars = matches[1];
}
```

Comment: [String.match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) returns null if no match was found. So instead of `matches.length > 1` you should simply use `matches`.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need regex to do that

```
var matches = /\[(.*?)\]/.exec(str1);
alert(matches[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach which avoids regex.

```
var str = "Point[A,B]";
var afterOpenBracket = str.split("[")[1]; // returns "A,B]"
var bracketContents = afterOpenBracket.split("]")[0]; // returns "A,B"
```

There, pretty simple! `bracketContents` now contains the entirety of the text between the first set of brackets.

We can stop here, but I'll go a step further anyway and split up the parameters.

```
var parameters = bracketContents.split(","); // returns ["A", "B"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Or in case u have more `[A,C,D,B]` and don't want to use regex:

```
var str1 = "Point[A,C,D,B]";

function extract(str1){
    var a = str1.charAt(str1.indexOf('[')+1);
    var b = str1.charAt(str1.indexOf(']')-1);

    return [a, b];  
        //or 
    //a.concat(b); //to get a string with that values
}

console.log(extract(str1));
```

Comment: Regex will work. And btw, your code wont work. It will return `AB`

Comment: @Abdul Munim the method with regex is great, i just offered other option